# Node.js app receives emit from browser, but browser does not receive emit back

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I can't seem to figure out why the node.js server connects fine, and receives an emit() from the browser fine, but when I try to emit() back from node.js it does not reach the browser. Am I missing something here?

The console log shows "Test Recieved" but not "Test Sent To Browser".

(index.php) snippet:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">       
        var socket = io.connect('https://www.example.com:2053', {secure: true});
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('join', '19AFA53df7715sfs484');
        });


        socket.on('testsend', function () {
            console.log('Test Sent To Browser');
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(this).on('click', '.mainlogo', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('testrecieve');
            });
        });

</script>
```

Socket code (pipe.js):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ca.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/file.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/file.crt')
};

var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

var https = require('https'),
server = https.createServer(options, app),
io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'});

server.listen(2053);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile('/index.php');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('join', function(uauth){
        socket.join('messages');
        socket.join(''+uauth+'');
    });

    socket.on('testrecieve', function () {
        socket.broadcast.emit('testsend');
        console.log('Test Recieved');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `socket.broadcast.emit` will send the message to all the other clients except the newly created connection. This is not what you want. You should use `socket.emit` instead.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, and that does work. But I really need to broadcast to a channel, for example, this does not work:
`socket.broadcast.to('messages').emit('testsend');`

Comment: If you want to broadcast to all sockets in a room, including socket which just connected, you have to use `io.to('messages').emit('testsend');`

Comment: @KevinJ I am not that familiar with channels in socket.io etc. for that I'd advise you to look up some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error, it is socket.emit, not socket.broadcast.emit

```
socket.on('testrecieve', function () {
    socket.emit('testsend');
    console.log('Test Recieved');
});
```

socket.broadcast.emit will send to everyone except the new connection.

Comment: You are correct, however, @giorgi-moniava beat you by 1 minute.

Comment: @KevinJ To be fair, I think Francois was first to answer. but my answer contained info why broadcast.emit usage was incorrect. Anyway.